# Android : cannot instantiate Dialog listener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, listener

I followed the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) to create a Dialog prompt on my app. It was working, but when I added the listener to process the data from the calling Fragment, I got a crash. It cannot instantiate the context as a listener. Here is some of my code :

The calling fragment :

```kotlin
class ConfigWifiFragment : Fragment(), BleManagerListener, WifiPasswordDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ConfigWifiFragment()
    }

    private var _binding: FragmentConfigWifiBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private var dialogPassword = WifiPasswordDialogFragment()

    //... some code

    private fun connectToWifiNetwork(ssid: String)
    {
        Log.i("Connection", ssid)
        Log.i("Context", context.toString())
        getFragmentManager()?.let { dialogPassword.show(it, "passwordWifi") }
    }

    override fun onDialogPositiveClick(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
        Log.i("ConfigWifi", dialog.config_wifi_password.text.toString())
    }

    override fun onDialogNegativeClick(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
        Log.i("ConfigWifi", "not ok")
    }
}
```

The dialog:

```kotlin
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

class WifiPasswordDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    internal lateinit var listener: NoticeDialogListener

    interface NoticeDialogListener {
        fun onDialogPositiveClick(dialog: DialogFragment)
        fun onDialogNegativeClick(dialog: DialogFragment)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface

        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            listener = context as NoticeDialogListener // CRASH
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw ClassCastException((context.toString() +
                    " must implement NoticeDialogListener"))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            // Get the layout inflater
            val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater;

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_wifi_password, null))
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.validation,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        // sign in the user ...
                        Log.i("dialog", "ok")
                        listener.onDialogPositiveClick(this)
                    })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        //getDialog().cancel()
                        Log.i("dialog", "Cancel")
                        listener.onDialogNegativeClick(this)
                    })
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}
```

The code crash in that line: `listener = context as NoticeDialogListener`, it cannot get the context as a `NoticeDialogListener` even if it's implemented in the calling fragment (and then the exception is thrown). I checked the ID of the context before showing the dialogue prompt, and the one inside; it's the same.

The only difference between my code and the example is I'm using a `Fragment` and not a `FragmentActivity`. How could I make works my code in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I don't know if it's the more elegant way, but here is it:

1st: I removed the `onAttach` function in my DialogFragment

2nd: I created a method to set the listener :

```kotlin
fun setListener(_listener : WifiPasswordDialogListener)
    {
        listener = _listener
    }
```

3rd: I called that method just before the `show` method:

```kotlin
private fun connectToWifiNetwork(ssid: String)
    {
        Log.i("Connection", ssid)
        Log.i("Context", context.toString())
        dialogPassword.setListener(this)
        getFragmentManager()?.let { dialogPassword.show(it, "passwordWifi") }
    }
```

I can now access to the data of my DialogBox from the calling fragment like this :

```kotlin
override fun onDialogPositiveClick(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        Log.i("ConfigWifi", dialog.dialog?.config_wifi_password?.text.toString())
    }
```